# Css float... when screen shrunk it comes out of div

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
#content_2 {position: 
absolute; 
top: 13%; 
left: -10px; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
z-index: 1;}

#content_image_2 {float: left; 
top: 13%; 
background-color: #ffffff; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
width: 70%; 
max-width: 70%; 
height: 30%; 
max-height: 30%; 
border-radius: 10px; 
white-space: nowrap;}

#content_image_2 img{float: right; 
min-height: 40%; 
max-height: 40%; 
width: auto;}
```

So i have these images inside a div.  They are set to float right.
When i shrink the screen they wrap and readjust their position inside the div.  Prefect! that is what i want, but when it gets too small the float images pop out of the div. I want to just not show up if the div is too small, but when i use overflow: hidden, the pages goes crazy and the floats don't work at all.

Does anyone know a way around this? or maybe another way to make this happen?

Comment: create a jsfiddle so that we can help you further

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mgu37d2z/

Comment: so they move around and reorder inside the div.

Comment: which is how i want it, but when screen is small they come out of the div and don't follow the rules of the div.

Comment: also someone edited my page which said the which div was inside which one.  Please check out the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the images if the div is too small you can use a media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   #content_image_2 img{
   display: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your `div` has an `id`, let's say, it is `my-div`. Whenever it is small, you want to hide the images inside it:

```
#my-div.small img {
    display: none;
}
```

Now, let's see how can we add/remove the `small` class:

```
function addClass(id, class) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!!element) {
        //prevent duplication of class name
        removeClass(id, class);
        element.className += " " + class;
    }
}

function removeClass(id, class) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!!element) {
        document.getElementById(id).className = document.getElementById(id).className.replace(/\bMyClass\b/,'');
    }
}
```

At the appropriate places check the `width` and `height` of the `div` and if it becomes small, add the `small` class, otherwise, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just turned the table into another div, and all the sizing / overflow css works.  I knew I shouldn't have used a table :/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JoeFrambach It provides a solution of some sort.